# `Self does not live long enough` generic associated types with lifetimes in async traits

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio, sqlx, generic-associated-types

I'm facing a problem with generic associated types and asynchronous rust.

The problem is: I want to be able to create a function called `transaction` in a trait `Connection` . This method basically creates a transaction and sends it in a callback function. If the callback returns Ok, we commit the transaction. Otherwise, we roll back. Simple, right? Here’s the code:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use futures::future::BoxFuture;

#[async_trait::async_trait]
trait Transaction: Send + Sync {
    async fn commit(self) -> Result<()>;

    async fn rollback(self) -> Result<()>;

    async fn query(
        &mut self,
        sql: &str,
    ) -> Result<()>;
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
trait Connection: Send + Sized {
    type Tx<'t>: Transaction
    where
        Self: 't;

    async fn begin(&self) -> Result<Self::Tx<'_>>;

    fn transaction<'a, F, R, E>(
        &'a mut self,
        callback: F,
    ) -> BoxFuture<Result<R, E>>
    where
        for<'c> F:
            FnOnce(&'c mut Self::Tx<'_>) -> BoxFuture<'c, Result<R, E>> + 'a + Send + Sync,
        R: Send,
        E: From<anyhow::Error> + Send,
    {
        Box::pin(async move {
            let mut tx = self.begin().await?;
            let ret = callback(&mut tx).await;

            match ret {
                Ok(ret) => {
                    tx.commit().await?;
                    Ok(ret)
                }
                Err(err) => {
                    tx.rollback().await?;
                    Err(err)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> { Ok(()) }
```

The problem is that I want to use a generic associated type in this trait called `Tx` that defines the transaction type.

The associated type has a generic lifetime ‘t, because the transaction is tied to the connection. That’s where the problem resides and it throws the error `Self does not live long enough`

Does anyone have any suggestions on top of that?

I tried to remove the generic associated type like [sqlx](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/) does, and it works. However I need to use a GAT.

## Edited

I found an answer to make it compile: change the return type of the function from `BoxFuture` to `LocalBoxFuture`.

That makes the code above compile fine, but that's not a reasonable solution for my current scenario because I need to guarantee `Send`ness. So, I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Why do you need to use a GAT? `trait Connection<'t>: Send + Sized where Self: 't`, removing `'t` from `Tx`, and then bounding `'a: 't` compiles, but it's not clear whether that fits your need.

Comment: I'm really trying to use GAT because that's how the codebase is already designed. The transaction type `Tx` needs a lifetime because it holds an exclusive reference to the inner driver types.

For example:

```rust
struct PgTransaction<'t> {
   inner: tokio_postgres::Transaction<'t>,
}
```